# How to convert UUID into 16 bytes UInt8 array in MacOS Objective C / C++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, macos, uuid

I can get UUID string using below code ..

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
```

Or I can get bytes using below code

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFUUIDBytes bytes = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(theUUID);
```

But I would like to make an array of UInt8 and as the UUID is 16 bytes, so the output array should be in 16 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By examining the [CFUUIDBytes typedef](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfuuidbytes?language=objc) you can see how to access each byte:

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFUUIDBytes bytes = CFUUIDGetUUIDBytes(theUUID);

UInt8 rawData[16];
rawData[0] = bytes.byte0;
rawData[1] = bytes.byte1;
...
rawData[15] = bytes.byte15;
```

Comment: Thanks @David H for your contribution, actually I have implemented that solution earlier. But Im looking for something else,  something more smarter.

Comment: Well you didn’t say that. But there is no better way. You don’t know the order in the raw structure and even if you determine it now, it could change later. That’s why Apple gave you one access method only. Do it Apples way or suffer the when they change things later.

Comment: I see, Thank you so much for the information @David H